# How can I prove that countable intersection of measurable sets has measure zero?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Your answers will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: as stated, the result is clearly false.. do you have a particular case in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can disprove it by using the collection $(-n,n); n=1,2,.....$.

Comment: Wow, downvoter does not like natural numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Not true as stated.

Suppose all the sets are the same.

Comment: And that set has non-zero measure ;).

Comment: However, do not ask me to prove anything significant in measure theory.